# Index out of bounds error for raster data extraction code

Tags: python

I am using a code written by Victor Velasquez to extract data from raster files which contain dayly precipitation data since 1981.
When I run the code, I get this error that some index is out of bounds. I did a little research and found that this is common and there are a lot of similar questions here, but I haven´t been able to find the specific solution for this case.

The error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-eff66ef74d73> in <module>
      1 Pisco = Extract_Pisco()
----> 2 Pisco.DataPre()
      3 Pisco.ExportExcel()

<ipython-input-7-6cf99336b9e1> in DataPre(self)
     23                 Band = Data.read(1)
     24                 X,Y  = Data.index(self.x,self.y) #extraigo
---> 25                 Pre  = Band[X,Y]
     26                 self.ListPre.append(Pre) #agrego a lista
     27 

IndexError: index 158116290 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 198
```

The part of the code pointed by the traceback is:

```
    def DataPre(self):
            os.chdir(path) 
            fileDir= path
            fileExt = r".tif" 
            Lis = [_ for _ in os.listdir(fileDir) if _.endswith(fileExt)]
            Lis.sort() #ordeno archivos .tif
            Inicio = '1981-01-01.tif' 
            Fin    = '2018-07-31.tif'  
            Rini = Lis.index(Inicio)
            Rend = Lis.index(Fin)
            self.Lis = Lis[Rini:Rend+1]
            self.ListPre = [] 
            for i in tnrange (0,len(self.Lis),desc = "!! Extrayendo Datos !!"):
                with rasterio.open(self.Lis[i]) as Data:
                    Band = Data.read(1)
                    X,Y  = Data.index(self.x,self.y)
                    Pre  = Band[X,Y] 
                    self.ListPre.append(Pre)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the file you are reading does not contain the geospatial point you are trying to find data for. (If this is incorrect please let me know).

You can add a statement to catch if a point is contained in the data:

```
                    Band = Data.read(1)
                    X,Y  = Data.index(self.x,self.y)
                    if 0 <= X < Band.height and 0 <= Y <= Band.width:
                        Pre  = Band[X,Y] 
                        self.ListPre.append(Pre)
```

Comment: That was it! I added a (lat,long) point and messed up the decimal separator, and therefore was out of boundaries of the raster file. Thank you!